# Meta box value pass to background color is it possible?

Tags: php, wordpress, meta-boxes

Post meta box value set to the background color or meta box value set to shortcode inline CSS is it possible?

Comment: Please share the code what you exaclty wants to do

Comment: Yes it is possible

Answer (score 0):

First you create `dynamic-style.php` in your css folder and put the code below

```
$absolute_path = explode('wp-content', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']);
$wp_load = $absolute_path[0] . 'wp-load.php';
require_once($wp_load);
header('Content-type: text/css');
header('Cache-control: must-revalidate');

//Get meta post table value

global $post;
$bgcolor_meta = get_post_meta($post->id, 'bgcolor_meta', true);

    $metacss = '';
if($bgcolor_meta){  
    $metacss .= '.news-events-bnr { //Your class or ID
        background-color: '.$bgcolor_meta.' !important;
    }';
}
echo $metacss;

/************ OR *************/

//Get option table value

$bgcolor = get_option('bgcolor');
$css = '';
if($bgcolor){  
    $css .= '.news-events-bnr { //Your class or ID
        background-color: '.$bgcolor.' !important;
    }';
}
echo $css;
```

Please add the enqueue script in your `function.php` like below

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_custom_scripts');
function add_custom_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_style('dynamic-style', esc_url(get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/css/dynamic-style.php'), '', true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can..

Get the meta box pass the metabox value in background-color like below

**style="background-color: ' . client_carousel_get_meta( 'client_carousel_carousel_bg_color' ) . '"**